# object in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redbean

I began use RedbeanPHP and Codeigniter. In Codeigniter manual written, that if you transmit object from controller to view - properties of object become arrays. 
I try get array ( object of redbeanphp ) in view from controller.
For example :

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()     {
        $this->load->library('rb');

        $post = R::dispense('post');
        $post->title = 'HI';
        $post->text = 'Hello World';
        $post->count = 5;

        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$post);
    }
}
```

I don't understand, how I must appeal to variable of array ?

```
<p><?php echo $????['title'] ;?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the variables for the templates as an array.

```
$this->load->view('welcome_message', array('something' => $post));
```

Then you can access it as `$something` in your template

Answer (score 0):

title is your key- so it itself becomes a variable in the view.
just use it like a normal variable-

```
<p><?php echo $title ;?></p>
```